# Installing Composer with autoload.php and use Aws\* says Class not found

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, composer-php

I'm running my php in cli under my user.

I have installed composer and autoloader.php does exist. Under vendor folders and file have been downloaded (autoload.php aws, bin, composer, guzzlehttp, mtdowling and psr)

Now in my php code I do:

```
// Include the SDK using the Composer autoloader
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Aws\Route53\Route53Client;
use Aws\Common\Credentials\Credentials;

$credentials = new Credentials('KEY', 'SECRETKEY');

$client = Route53Client::factory(array(
    'credentials' => $credentials
));
```

When I run the script I get: PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Credentials' not found in /home/user/updatedns.php on line 15

I tried running it a sudo also (in case it needs to write to the directory) and still get this error.

Comment: Just found out that use Aws\Common\Credentials\Credentials; is now under use Aws\Credentials\Credentials;

Answer (score 1):

Just found out that use Aws\Common\Credentials\Credentials; is now under use Aws\Credentials\Credentials;